# what is requery in vb6?

Tags: sql, vb6

what is requery in vb6? how to use that one? can anyone help ?

Comment: Huh? What is required for doing what?

Comment: i have a recordset in vb6. and i want to insert that into datbase table. I am new to vb6 and sql. I dont know how to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ADO Requery method is explained here, maybe it helps: http://www.w3schools.com/ado/met_rs_requery.asp

From the linked page:

> The Requery method updates the data in a Recordset by re-executing the
>   query that made the original Recordset.
>
> Tip: Use this method to refresh the entire contents of a Recordset.
>
> Note: With this method you call the Close and Open methods in one.